# dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, 15.10, texlive

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, I used

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But the I get the following:

Errors were encountered while processing:

```
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-base-doc_2015.20150625-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that the system has issues with my texmaker. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?