# installation problem of texlive in Xubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, texlive

While installing texlive in Xubuntu 16.04.1, it does not install properly.  When I upgrade the system it shows me the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: texlive-lang-english (>= 2015) but it is not installed
                Depends: texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2015) but it is not installed
                Depends: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2015) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That did not work.  I also tried Synaptic but it gives me the following error

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-lang-english_2015.20160223-1_all.deb: cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-recommended-doc_2015.20160320-1_all.deb: cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/eso-pic/eso-ex4.tex' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/eso-pic/eso-ex4.tex.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
```

please help me

Comment: give the output of dkpg  --configure  -a

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-full:
 texlive-full depends on texlive-lang-english (>= 2015); however:
 Package texlive-lang-english is not installed.
 texlive-full depends on texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2015); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended-doc is not installed.
 texlive-full depends on texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2015); however:
 Package texlive-latex-base-doc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-full

Comment: try purging textlive and reinstalling from synaptic. `sudo apt purge textlive*`

Comment: I could be a problem of outdated sources. I suggest to purge (as comment above), and install following [these instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/77895). There are very clear and will give you **the latest stable** texlive distro, unlike the one installed using Synaptic or `apt-get`, which can be relatively outdated.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when upgrading from Ubuntu LTS 14.04 to LTS 16.04.1. I could not remove textlive* using the suggestion by [rancho](https://askubuntu.com/users/492332/rancho). Then I found a solution by [vehka](https://askubuntu.com/users/100766/vehka) on how to remove texlive-latex-base-doc:
[apt-get broken after version update (unmet dependencies)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744585/apt-get-broken-after-version-update-unmet-dependencies)

```
$ sudo dpkg --force-all --purge texlive-latex-base-doc
```

It is also important to remove all packages carefully otherwise reinstallation will not work. I followed the steps that I took from a comment given by [mubeena](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/81858/mubeena) in a comment to a solution given by [Nate Eldredge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56646/nate-eldredge) for mubeena's own thread: [many many dpkg errors while upgrading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151948/many-many-dpkg-errors-while-upgrading):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge tex-common texlive-*
$ sudo rm /etc/texmf/
```

Based on the other error that you are getting, you might need to remove also texlive-lang-english by using

```
$ sudo dpkg --force-all --purge texlive-lang-english
```

Then you could do

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

and finally

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

This last command will install all you need and more. You might want to explore other detailed or lighter versions of texlive installation, but probably installing everythin will simplify things for you. I share the explanation by [ufos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/64479/ufos) in the following thread: [Installation of texlive-full on Ubuntu 12.04](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134365/installation-of-texlive-full-on-ubuntu-12-04), but there is a nice breakdown by [masroor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14103/masroor) if you want to install just what you need.

Comment: This is the most useful forum post I've seen all week - thanks!