# texlive-plain-generic broke my Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade process

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, texlive

When I update and upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04.3 recently, I got the following error messages:

`qxd@NapaValley:~/SoftwareRepo/simnanophotonics$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-formats-extra : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
 texlive-full : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
 texlive-generic-recommended : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
 texlive-lang-arabic : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
 texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
qxd@NapaValley:~/SoftwareRepo/simnanophotonics$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  texlive-plain-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  texlive-plain-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
151 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 53.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 414323 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-plain-generic_2017.20170818-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-plain-generic (2017.20170818-1~16.04.york0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-plain-generic_2017.20170818-1~16.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/bin/tex4ht.jar', which is also in package texlive-binaries 2017.20170613.44585-1~16.04.york0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-plain-generic_2017.20170818-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

- So, I have tried unisntall `texlive-full` and dependencies completely using `sudo dpkg --purge *` and then reinstall `texlive-full` with the well-known third party PPA (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive`), the same error occurs afterwards. I have also tried [this linked way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) to uninstall texlive.
- `sudo apt-get install -f` didn't fix anything.
- I have also tried `sudo dpkg --force-all --purge texlive-plain-generic` following [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744585/apt-get-broken-after-version-update-unmet-dependencies), but no luck.

With this unmet dependencies error, I cannot install any upgrades or new packages. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, which seems working for now, is the following.

1. Purge the third-party PPA for texlive

   `sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive
   sudo update`
2. Purge all texlive packages as I did before. Plus, purge a easy-to-mess-up package by `sudo apt purge libkpathsea6`.
3. Reinstall texlive from the beginning, `sudo apt install texlive-full`.